# mapview problems when running on device

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have an app that uses a google MapView.  It runs well on the AVD but sometimes does not run well on my LG Optimus Elite Android phone.  When I start the app on the phone, when the phone is getting a Wi-Fi signal, the map does not show - it shows only the light grid marks.  Sometimes it will not show the map for 20 minutes, sometimes it shows the map after 5 minutes.  If I go drive around with the phone and it leaves Wi-Fi and goes to 3G, the map usually appears after a minute or so.

The MapView is defined as follows...

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="my key goes here"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

When I start the app up, I do the following...

```
static MapView myMapView;
static MapController mc;

myMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);    
myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mc = myMapView.getController();   
mc.setZoom(20);
myMapView.setSatellite(true);
myMapView.setTraffic(false);    
myMapView.invalidate(); //(tried both with and without this invalidate)
```

Again, the map shows right away in the AVD emulator.

Is there something I need to be doing to kickstart this map?

Comment: do you use a debug key or a release key ?

Answer (score 0):

That is typically an API key problem. You need to set the API KEY here:

```
 android:apiKey="my key goes here"
```

Comment: I don't think it's an api key problem.  If it were, the map would never appear.  In his case it's shown after some (very long) period of time.

Comment: But do  you have a ket set instead of "my key goes here"?

Comment: This is not my question, but I'm sure the OP does.

Comment: I am not sure what OP means, and you may have another problem on top of the key, but one thing is certain: the MapView won't work without at least a debug api key

Comment: NathanZ, you are kidding, right?  I obviously don't want to publish my real API key on this forum.

Comment: OK, so just say "yes, I have a key set"

Answer (score 0):

In general the map should appear in the device as fast as it appears in the emulator.

I've had once a stupid bug in my app, that lead to a similar behaviour. It's very unlike that you will have exactly the same problem, but can give you a hint on what could lead to that behaviour.

Basicly, I had something like:

```
private Runnable myRunable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //do something
    mHandler.postDelayed(myRunable , delay);    
    }
};
```

Allowing delay to be `0`, it results in continous loop and a very high CPU utilization.

Strangely, in the emulator, although slower it worked. In the device, it took ages to have the map drawn in the screen.

Regards.

Comment: Don't think that's my case but is there any way to tell how much CPU our app is using?

Comment: I think it depends on Adroid version, but usually in the phone setting, `Battery` menu shows the applications with more CPU usage. So, if you restart your device and leave your app running alona for 10 minutes, it should show just a few of secounds of CPU utilization. It it shows more then that I would suspect that something is wrong.